# How do you switch roles in Watchdogs multiplayer?

Tags: watch-dogs

For instance in online hacking, I am always the hacker or in ctOS Mobile Community I'm always the one racing through the city.

How do I play as the other person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actively choose to get invaded.

It happens when you're invaded by another player when playing normally.

[IGN description](http://www.ign.com/wikis/watch-dogs/Multiplayer#Invasion)

Comment: So do I just play single player and it randomly happens then?

Comment: Yes. I usually see it happen when trying to start a quest and it tells me that I'm being invaded and have to find the invader first.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of these things if you want to get hacked in Watch Dogs instead of being the hacker:

- I've found it happens more when you are around ctOS towers and when you have a bounty from Blume.
- It never happens during a mission that I can tell.
- I've yet to have it happen in Multiplayer Free Roam, but that was what I was originally told.
- Best thing you can do is just play and enjoy the times you get hacked if that is your sort of thing.   It keeps it mysterious